Azure Pipelines, Can the Pipeline 'Default branch for manual and scheduled builds' be updated using rest APIs?
I have got the pipeline url using rest APIs, now I want to update the it's default branch (not default branch of repository) using rest APIs.
Any way to do it?
Answer on one similar question Can I set "Default branch for manual and scheduled builds" for a pipeline in Azure DevOps using an API? points to Update Build Rest APIs , when I tried that, the resulting json has no 'defaultbranch' key.
And this is logical because UPDATE BUILD RestApi belongs to a specific run of a pipeline and 'Default Branch for manual and scheduled builds' is for a pipeline, not it's runs.

This question is similar to: Can I set "Default branch for manual and scheduled builds" for a pipeline in Azure DevOps using an API?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@RuiJarimba I had already tried that solution but didn't work, reason updated in the question now.

Hi @cris7ronaldo, have you assigned your account with at least "Edit build pipeline" permission of your target pipeline and vso.build_execute scope of your PAT? Are the scripts below working now?

You can use REST API Definitions - Update to change the default branch of one pipeline.

Run Definitions - Get to get the JSON body of your pipeline's definition.
Change the value of repository.defaultBranch to your target branch.
Run Definitions - Update with the new value of repository.defaultBranch.

Refer to the following PowerShell scripts.
$token = "{PAT}"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/build/definitions/{BuildDefinitionId}?api-version=7.1-preview.7"
$definition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method GET -Headers $head -ContentType application/json
$definition.repository.defaultBranch = "refs/heads/{TargetBranchName}"
$json = ConvertTo-Json $definition -Depth 20
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method PUT -Headers $head -Body $json -ContentType application/json


I tried this in bash and got an error 'The Git repository does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting' What permission are required? And will this update the default branch of repository or 'default branch of manual and scheduled builds'? I want to execute the later.


You need to have at least "Edit build pipeline" permission of your target pipeline. If you are a member of "Contributors" group in the project, you will have the permission to edit the pipeline by default. The PAT needs vso.build_execute scope at least. 2. The PowerShell scripts above is used to update the 'default branch of manual and scheduled builds".

